# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android

Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $. Всё работало нормально, потом вырубило свет. При запуске появилась ошибка. Что делать?

Ошибка влогах

```
2020-01-15 19:10:22.051 21495-21495/com.example.eftguide E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.eftguide, PID: 21495
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.eftguide-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.eftguide-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:807)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5651)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1685)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:939)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:829)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.eftguide-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.eftguide-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:996)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:801)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5651) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1685) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6397) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:939) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:829)
```

Comment: Покажите что вам приходит с сервера. Если это с сервера JSON. А может это у вас при сборке такое? В общем не хватает деталей для ответа.

Comment: это при сборке такое появилось

Comment: Попробуйте `Invalidate cache and restart` из меню студии сделать.

Comment: Сделал. теперь новая ошибка. Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK
The APKs are invalid.

Comment: У меня получилось на эмуляторе запустить. Напрямую через телефон не работает почему-то.

Comment: Заработало, я не знаю в чём была причина, но я просто сначала запустил на эмуляторе а потом на телефоне.